# High precision timer

Tags: delphi, timer, precision, delphi-xe5, onkeyup

I am working on a stopwatch application, specifically for sport stacking and speed cubing (solving the Rubik's cube in the shortest time possible).

I want the program to start a stopwatch that displays the elapsed time in the format 00:00.00 with minutes, seconds and split seconds to 2 decimal places when the spacebar is pressed and then stop the timer when the spacebar is pressed again.

I have tried many options and downloaded source code and various stopwatch classes to try and solve my problem but when I run the program parallel to a real stopwatch, my timer lags behind. I cannot seem to get the code right for a precise timer that starts and stops when the spacebar is pressed.

I am working in Delphi XE5. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Post what you have and someone will help you fix it.

Comment: _"I have tried many options..."_ show us that. Right now, the question lacks research effort.

Comment: Keep in mind that a windows based application will always have some uncontrollable amount of error in the milliseconds to tens of milliseconds range, if not more.  There's a reason that competitions use hardware timers, and that's simply because Windows can't guarantee how long the delay will be between a key being pressed and your application being notified (and further, between your application being notified and it actually doing something about it).  When you're talking about cubing times where 10ms makes a big difference, well...

Comment: StackOverflow is a difficult community. Why people are so quickly downvoting (especially a beginner) instead of helping improving the question (as @500-InternalServerError did)?

Comment: @Altar: I didn't downvote,but I'd suspect it's because StackOverflow has quality guidelines, and all questions (including those posted by a beginner) must meet those guidelines. The guidelines are provided to new users when they register here (in the [tour]) and are available in the [help] at all times. Writing the words "I have tried many options" does not show any effort, and questions asking about why code isn't working need to include that code. If you want to discuss SO's quality requirements, post on [meta] to do so, not here.

Answer (score 3):

**First reflection**

Before I continue, some reflections:

- If there is a lag when you start the timer due to latency between
  the *user - keyboard - code* then shouldn't there be a relatively equal
  lag when the spacebar is pressed again to stop the timer?
- Windows is not a real-time operating system. If your application requires
  real-time precision, you may want to select another platform.
- A cordless keyboard may increase the lag...

**Detect key press**

I can think of two different mechanisms to detect if the spacebar has been pressed:

- OnKeyDown - Standard Delphi event based on window messaging (Slow??)
- [GetAsyncKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Reads the physical state of the keyboard, regardless of the input queue state. (Faster??)

**Benchmarck**

Below is an example where I benchmark between the two mechanisms using a `TStopwatch`. TStopwatch uses operating system-dependent functionality to gain access to high-resolution timers, if available; otherwise, the usual timers are used. I've placed the GetAsyncKeyState function in it's own thread.

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.AppEvnts, Winapi.ShellApi, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,

  //Add these two units
  System.Diagnostics, System.TimeSpan;

type
  TThreadCheckSpaceKey = class(TThread)
  private
    FStopwatch : TStopwatch;
  public
    property Stopwatch : TStopwatch read FStopWatch;
    constructor Create();
    procedure Execute(); override;
 end;

  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  private
    FThreadCheckSpaceKey : TThreadCheckSpaceKey;
    FStopwatch : TStopwatch;
    procedure DoDrawTimer;
  public

  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TimeSpanToStr(aTimeSpan : TTimeSpan):string;
begin
  result := Format('%.*d', [2, aTimeSpan.Minutes])+ ':' +
            Format('%.*d', [2, aTimeSpan.Seconds]) + ':' +
            Copy(Format('%.*d', [3, aTimeSpan.Milliseconds]), 1, 3);
end;

procedure TFormMain.DoDrawTimer();
begin
  //This is just an example
  Caption := 'GetAsyncKeyState: ' + TimeSpanToStr(FThreadCheckSpaceKey.Stopwatch.Elapsed) + ' OnKeyDown: ' + TimeSpanToStr(FStopWatch.Elapsed);;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  FThreadCheckSpaceKey.Terminate;

  FreeAndNil(FThreadCheckSpaceKey);
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //If in the Delphi IDE then report memory leaks on shutdown
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;

  FStopwatch := TStopWatch.Create;

  FThreadCheckSpaceKey := TThreadCheckSpaceKey.Create;

  //Clear any previos records of the space key being pressed
  GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE);
end;

procedure TFormMain.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  DoDrawTimer;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_SPACE then begin
    if FStopwatch.IsRunning then
       FStopwatch.Stop
    else
       FStopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

    Key := 0; //Don't propogate to underlyning controls
    DoDrawTimer;
  end;
end;

{ TThreadCheckSpaceKey}

function GetBit(Value: SHORT; Index: Byte): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ((Value shr Index) and 1) = 1;
end;

constructor TThreadCheckSpaceKey.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FStopwatch := TStopWatch.Create;
end;

procedure TThreadCheckSpaceKey.Execute;
var IsDown : boolean;
begin
  inherited;

  while not Terminated do begin
       //If the lowest bit is set then the space bar has been pressed since last check
       //If the higest bit is set then the space bar is down
       if GetBit(GetAsyncKeyState( VK_SPACE ), 15) then begin

          if not IsDown  then
             if FStopwatch.IsRunning then
                FStopwatch.Stop
             else
                FStopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
          IsDown := true;
       end
       else
         IsDown := false;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is not how to build a stopwatch, but how to get a precise time measure without lagging. I can't see anything related to this in your answer.

Comment: Point taken Sir Rufo. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` may actually be less performant since you would have to poll in a busy loop that could accumulate errors up to, at least, the thread time slice interval.  Keyboard messages, on the other hand, are triggered by interrupts that directly wake threads waiting on messages, making the response quite quick.  Regardless of the implementation, however, no software timer can ever guarantee accuracy 100% of the time.  Given that you can buy a stackmat for $25 and even a cheap PC for twenty times that price...sometimes it's best to use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Also worth noting that, as yet, we still don't even know what OP means when they say `...my timer lags behind`.  Is it off by thousandths, hundredths, tenths... seconds??  It's always better to wait for OP to show us their code first so that there is an opportunity to help them correct it rather than simply to give them a working copy-paste answer.